# Efficient data structure that checks for existence of String

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, arraylist, hashmap

I am writing a program which will add a growing number or unique strings to a data structure. Once this is done, I later need to constantly check for existence of the string in it.

If I were to use an ArrayList I believe checking for the existence of some specified string would iterate through all items until a matching string is found (or reach the end and return false).

However, with a HashMap I know that in constant time I can simply use the key as a String and return any non-null object, making this operation faster. However, I am not keen on filling a HashMap where the value is completely arbitrary. Is there a readily available data structure that uses hash functions, but doesn't require a value to be placed?

Comment: You mean like a `HashSet`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I were to use an ArrayList I believe checking for the existence of some specified string would iterate through all items until a matching string is found

Correct, checking a list for an item is linear in the number of entries of the list.

> However, I am not keen on filling a HashMap where the value is completely arbitrary

You don't have to: Java provides a [`HashSet<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class, which is very much like a `HashMap` without the value part.

You can put all your strings there, and then check for presence or absence of other strings in constant time;

```
Set<String> knownStrings = new HashSet<String>();
... // Fill the set with strings

if (knownString.contains(myString)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on many factors, including the number of strings you have to feed into that data structure (do you know the number by advance, or have a basic idea?), and what you expect the hit/miss ratio to be.

A very efficient data structure to use is a trie or a radix tree; they are basically made for that. For an explanation of how they work, see [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (a followup to the radix tree definition is in this page). There are Java implementations (one of them is [here](https://github.com/parboiled1/grappa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/parboiled1/grappa/matchers/trie); however I have a fixed set of strings to inject, which is why I use a builder).

If your number of strings is really huge *and* you don't expect a minimal miss ratio then you might also consider using a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter); the problem however is that it is probabilistic; but you can get very quick answers to "not there". Here also, there are implementations in Java (Guava has an implementation for instance).

Otherwise, well, a `HashSet`...

Comment: +1 for a trie, that's the canonical data structure for this particular job

Answer (score 1):

A HashSet is probably the right answer, but if you choose (for simplicity, eg) to search a list it's probably more efficient to concatenate your words into a String with separators:

```
String wordList = "$word1$word2$word3$word4$...";
```

Then create a search argument with your word between the separators:

```
String searchArg = "$" + searchWord + "$";
```

Then search with, say, `contains`:

```
bool wordFound = wordList.contains(searchArg);
```

You can maybe make this a tiny bit more efficient by using StringBuilder to build the searchArg.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned `HashSet` is the way to go. But if the size is going to be large and you are fine with false positives (checking if the username exists) you can use **[BloomFilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)** (probabilistic data structure) as well.